# How to add a UISegmentedControl to Section header of UITableView with margin?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I recently added a segmented control to a section header of my tableview, everything works fine, but it resizes the wrong way .. i want to apply some margin, but if i set the frame it does not have any effect on the size of the segmented control ? What i am doing wrong ? here is my code :

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(section == 0) {
        UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"Segment 1", @"Segment 2",@"Segment 3"]];
        segmentedControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.95];
        [segmentedControl setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width-10, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

        return segmentedControl;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning UISegmentedControl instance and for obvious reasons you can't configure much inside the control. Instead of that try to create a UIView as a header view and add segmented control inside as a subview. This way you will be able to configure position of segmented control inside this container view just fine.

Answer (score 5):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if(section == 0) {

        UIView * viewHeader = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width-10, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
        [viewHeader setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"Segment 1", @"Segment 2",@"Segment 3"]];
        segmentedControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.95];
        [segmentedControl setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, viewHeader.frame.size.width , viewHeader.frame.size.height)];
        viewHeader addSubview:segmentedControl

        return viewHeader;
    }
    return nil;
}
```